How can I optimize MongoDB connections across multiple databases for faster search?
I am working on a project that involves connecting to multiple MongoDB databases (each containing around 3 million users). I’m connecting to all of them in parallel and performing a search across these databases. However, I feel that the process is slower than it could be. Below is the code I’ve written.
config.js (Contains the URLs for the databases)
export const dbURLs = [
  // TODO: Refactor this approach
  // Each URL has 3 million of Users
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_1,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_2,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_3,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_4,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_5,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_6,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_7,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_8,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_9,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_10,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_11,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_12,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_13,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_14,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_15,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_16,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_17,
  process.env.DATABASE_URL_18,
];

db.js (Establishes a connection to all databases in parallel)
async function connectToDatabases() {
  const databases = [];
  
  // Connecting in parallel
  await Promise.all(
    dbURLs.map(async (url, index) => {
      try {
        const client = new MongoClient(url, {
          maxPoolSize: 19,
          minPoolSize: 1,
        });
        await client.connect();
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        databases.push(db);
        console.log(`Successfully connected: ${index}`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to connect to database at ${index}: ${error.message}`);
      }
    })
  );
  
  return databases;
}

searchController.js (Searches for a specific user across all databases)
const databases = await connectToDatabases();
let accountFound = false;
let accounts = [];

for (const db of databases) {
  const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
  const account = await collection.find({ id: facebook_id }).toArray();
  if (account.length > 0) {
    accountFound = true;
    accounts.push(...account);
    break;
  }
}
// other code

Is there a more efficient way to handle connections and search across these databases?
How can I reduce the time spent in connecting and querying the databases?

So the general assumption with MongoDB is that related data that is queried together should be stored together. My initial thought would be to compile the databases into a single one for centralized management. Either way, the issue requires significantly more context and details to investigate and give a meaningful conclusion, which is unlikely to fit in a single SO question.

1. What's the reason for separating the DB's like that? Querying 20 Databases with 3 mil records each is much much worse than one DB with 60 mil records. 2. Not sure how async JS code is meant to be written but your code may not actually be async. The contents of the for (const db of databases) loop should be it's own async function which should then be await'ed 20 times, so that they can have async something.join() and all run in parallel. If you add logs, I think you'll see that your current code basically runs sequentially for the array of DBs.

Why do you have 20 different databases? If you have so much data, then use a sharded cluster.

Connecting to the database should not be the bottleneck, because you do it only once when you launch your application. You have to optimize the query. Most likely one single database will be faster.

First of all, you have to consider about having multiple databases for the same type of data. Maybe there was a decision to split single database into multiple for data distribution across different machines. If that, I can give a piece of advice to take into account MongoDB Sharding feature: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/sharding/
Second, instead of performing connections at request time, I insist to move connections initialisation to your application's initialisation phase. That way you will be able to use connections at request time without spending a precious time for theirs initialisation. Also, that way you can negate memory leaks, because once you create a connection, it will be reserved until it is released, so it is best practice to reserve connections at startup and to release them at application's close. Otherwise, every request will reserve more and more connections until you will reach theirs limit: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/
Next, make sure your collections (in each database you use) have an index for your id field. Otherwise, it will cause a huge performance issues. You can start with single field index: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/index-single/#std-label-indexes-single-field
Next, consider about the pagination. I see, you using .toArray method which immediately fetches all documents over a network from your database. If that's what you need, I can recommend to add some projections (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) if your documents contain more data that it is needed, so that you can reduce amount of bytes to be transferred over a network.
Finally, your code doesn't perform parallel search. Moreover, your code will  stop searching once it found at least one user - was it on purpose? If not, you can significantly improve your performance (and also make your code a little bit smaller) next way:
const accountsPromises = databases.map((db) => {
  const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
  return collection.find({ id: facebook_id }).toArray();
});
const accountsArrays = await Promise.all(accountsPromises);
return accountsArrays.flat();

P.S.  if you are using cursors directly, be aware that according to the documentation (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/#close) you have to close your cursors in order to avoid memory and network leaks
